# javascript not working in Squarespace but it's working outside of it

Tags: javascript, iframe, squarespace, iframe-resizer

I am trying to embed the Iframe from the client and the form needs to be resized depending on the individual information. They suggested we use the resize.js (https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) to resize it. The CSS "Height:auto" is not working here.

I added the js files and everything and it works on the browser fine opening from my (.html) file. But it doesn't work on squarespace and found out later that it doesn't work on CodePen too. Below is the Code pen link.

[codepen`  $(function(){

```
    var iFrames = $('iframe');

    function iResize() {

        for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
          iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';}
        }

        if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) { 

           iFrames.load(function(){
               setTimeout(iResize, 0);
           });

           for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
                var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
                iFrames[i].src = '';
                iFrames[i].src = iSource;
           }

        } else {
           iFrames.load(function() { 
               this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
           });
        }

    });
```

`][1](https://codepen.io/MayTA/pen/zYrYOwB)

Answer (score 0):

You code will only work same domain, you need to use the library you referenced in your question.